# «Я готов рассказать тебе поле…» – как понять эту фразу?

Tags: запятые, семантика, поэзия

**Персидские мотивы** в творчестве поэта...

«В 1924 году Есенин приехал в Баку с твердой целью – получить разрешение пересечь границу и ступить на персидскую землю. Его притягивала эта восточная культура - как поэта, как читателя».
https://zen.yandex.ru/media/litinteres/shagane-ty-moia-shagane-o-kom-napisal-esenin-6028cb91c219c97e32f23948

Но оказалось, что притягивало не только это…

*Шаганэ ты моя, Шаганэ!*

*Потому, что я с севера, что ли,*

***Я готов рассказать тебе поле**,*

*Про волнистую рожь при луне.*

*Шаганэ ты моя, Шаганэ.*

Меня же заинтересовала фраза «*Я готов рассказать тебе поле*» и знаки препинания. **Почему «поле»?** Это не обращение, ведь запятой нет, а что? И почему стоит вторая запятая?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Если рассказать поле — это метафора (= рассказать про поле), то не лучше ли было оформить ее с использованием пояснительной конструкции:

***Я готов рассказАть тебе пОле —***

*Про волнистую рожь при луне.*

Comment: Вы  (четко и уверенно) прочитаете  так: « Я готов рассказать тебе pОle,  // Про волнистую рОжь при луне». На слух вас вообще никто не поймет – какое «pоle»  вы хотите рассказать (может быть, так сказка или история называется, по-персидски например). Шаганэ точно бы не поняла. А надо прочитать так: «Я готов рассказАть / тебе… пОле  /, Про волнистую рОжь при луне». Две очень маленькие паузы вместо одной большой и ударение на «рассказать».

Comment: Это мне комментарий? Если да, то чего он здесь? Если нет, то кому?

Comment: А кому же еще. С того "поля" вы скоро отправитесь в чат.

Comment: Но я случайно заметил, мог и не заметить. Ещё до 20 сообщений там далековато. Кстати, если использовать @, то оповещение о новом сообщении в чате тоже приходит. Минус в том, что там нельзя удалять сообщения через 5 минут. С маленькими ударением на "поле" и паузой оно похоже на обращение. Меня всё устраивает, если прочитать по варианту Есенина.

Comment: Вас устраивает, а Шагане – нет.

Comment: Вклинюсь немного. Меня тоже устраивает такой строй. Когда читаешь впервые, то, конечно, бросается в глаза этот "нонсенс", а потом понимаешь, что автор хотел сказать:  представить, объяснить, показать, нарисовать и пр. Мне понравилось такое необычное сочетание и вольность.  А с запятыми после "потому" тоже всё в порядке.

Comment: А Шаганэ, я думаю, вообще не в претензии: если носитель русского так говорит, значит, правильно :)

Comment: Наверное, да, она  же доверчивая. Да я не против этой метафоры, просто думаю, как ее правильно оформить. Чтобы не с третьего раза понимать :)

Comment: Вопреки своим же принципам я не буду обстоятельно и аргументированно отвечать на основной поставленный вопрос - о пунктуации. Полагаю, тут пунктуация вторична и отчасти факультативна, но при этом и автор не ошибся, выбрав (возможно, чисто интуитивно) такое оформление. А вот в отношении того, что имелось в виду при использовании особого управления "рассказать поле" - это действительно предмет для обсуждения. Да, наверное, это метафора. "Поле" заменяет слово "повесть" или "рассказ". Во всяком случае иного я нигде не встречал - за исключением не слишком солидных утверждений, что это грамматическа

Comment: «Поле» в этом стихотворении — это рассказ или повесть? Вы первый человек в истории, кто читает этот стих и видит здесь не поле, где сажают картоплю, а вид произведения, как повесть или рассказ. Если слово «поле» обозначает вид литературного произведения, то в чем же факультативность этой пунктуации? И тогда получается, что у Есенина было авторское значение слов. Это известно, что Есенин называл дом словом «выдра», а дерево называл словом «лошадь».

Comment: @JimKorbett - вопрос в чем? Вы не понимаете, что такое "метафора"? Видимо да, но даже это не дает вам права утверждать, что я - "первый человек в истории".  ))))

Comment: А вы понимаете разницу между фигуральным приемом и деменцией? Если, вместо «мне стыдно», человек говорит «моя грудь горит огнем», то это — фигуральный прием; если, вместо «пойду в дом», человек говорит «пойду в енота», это — деменция.

Comment: @JimKorbett по сути вашего первого замечания я вам ответил в тексте ответа. Второе оставляю без комментария по причине неприемлемости формы и абсолютного несоответствия теме.

Comment: Надо же! Я думал, что Есенин просто поехавший и общается с полем, а оказывается, это фигуральный прием. То, что поле это символ тоски по родине — хорошо, но при чем здесь слова «повесть», «рассказ». Эти слова обозначают озвученную или записанную историю некий событий. Путать слова «повесть» и «рассказ» и «символ» — это деменция.

Comment: И причем все это к пунктуации?! Как всё это объясняет отсутствие этой несчастной запятой?!

Comment: *рассказать тебе поле, про волнистую рожь при луне* — здесь, скорее всего, уточнение, а не однородные члены. Это же как бы одно и то же (рожь — то, из чего состоит поле).

Comment: @oleedd *здесь, скорее всего, уточнение, а не однородные члены.* - Так я-то как раз и возражаю против этой традиционной трактовки. Во-первых, грамматически не вяжется (управление разное - там, где уточнение требует одинакового), а во-вторых, по смыслу не очень получается. Ну про смысл - это см. текст моего ответа.

Comment: Сказанул человек что-то неладное, а потом поясняет. Не требуется одинаковое управление: *расскажу тебе сказку, про волшебное королевство; смотрел фильм, про боевые искусства; он придёт завтра, в семь часов [или после обеда]; купил йогурт, со вкусом клубники*. Если бы было что-то не связанное с полем, то однородные без вопросов. Что-то не сильно понял, что не так со смыслом. Да, он раскрывается далее, но как раз через уточнение, потому что однородные элементы самостоятельны и не в силах раскрывать смысл предыдущего элемента.

Answer (score 2):

Это художественное, хотя перебор. Но ведь в стихах часто перебор (чрезмерная свобода), что связано среди прочего с острой необходимостью рифмы.

По аналогии с "рассказать сказку", "рассказать историю". То есть "поле" — это как та информация о поле, которая передаёт всё его **естество**. А дальше идёт уточнение.

Средний по корректности (в сравнении с данными примерами) вариант (разговорный): *рассказать фильм*.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, но я не очень понимаю. Рассказать сказку или даже фильм — это всегда пожалуйста, но как можно рассказать "поле". Допустим, это авторское понимание слова, но как раскрыть эту метафору? Какое отношение она имеет к словарному значению слова "поле"?

Comment: Вообще-то понятно, если заменить  - рассказать о поле.  Но грамматика очень неудачная, тем более что дальше следует предлог ПРО. Хотя бы тире надо поставить! Я готов рассказать тебе поле – про волнистую рожь при луне.

Comment: Говорю же, что перебор, но замысел доступен для понимания. *Рассказать фильм* — это не есть корректно, надо: *рассказать сюжет фильма*. В фильм входят и костюмы, и детали интерьера, невозможно всё это рассказать.

Comment: Рассказать фильм - это просторечный вариант, а рассказать поле —  метафора,  она должна быть более понятной. Нужно ТИРЕ. Пояснительное, для раскрытии метафоры. Я не уверена, что она всем понятна. А если и понятна, то грамматика раздражает слух. И кавычки не помешали бы, для особо непонятливых.

Comment: Если тире, то это будет всё, что он хочет рассказать, а с запятой это лишь пример.

Comment: Или еще вариант: Я готов рассказать тебе — поле, Про волнистую рожь при луне.  Так и надо читать, с паузой.  Наверняка этот вариант  был  задуман у Есенина :))

Comment: А что меняется? Просто пауза, на мой взгляд ненужная.

Comment: Что за прагматизм! Поэт на секунду задумался, подбирая нужное слово. Пауза должна быть маленькой, слегка обозначенной.

Comment: Хотя... что-то в этом есть. Можно и с паузой. Но это не связано с тем, что он задумался.

Comment: А с чем связано? Дальше! А если многоточие поставить?

Comment: Связано с интонационным подчёркиванием при нестандартной грамматической стыковке. По Розенталю, тире отражает **неожиданность**, переломный момент (здесь грамматический). Многоточие — это когда задумался, а здесь чёткая, уверенная речь.

Comment: oleedd, вы похожи на кибермозг: останавливаетесь, задумываетесь над своими словами и от себя самого ждете продолжения. И всё-то у вас четко и уверенно. Если оставить такую пунктуацию, то предложение будет прочитано неверно в ста случаях из ста. На месте тире надо сделать маленькую паузу,  а дальше все читать слитно, в одну фразу, не обособляя уточнение. Вот это будет художественно.

Comment: *останавливаетесь, задумываетесь над своими словами и от себя самого ждете продолжения* — что-то не понял. *Если оставить такую пунктуацию, то предложение будет прочитано неверно в ста случаях из ста* — что значит "прочитано неверно"? Может, предложение не будет понято верно? Не понимаю, как можно без запятой перед "про".

Comment: Интересный вопрос!  Я завтра отвечу, а вы — сегодня, ОК? 
 https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467330/Почему-здесь-присутствуют-эти-запятые

Comment: Ответил........

Answer (score 2):

Из словаря управления:
[рассказать — рассказывать](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/2119/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
**1.** [раскрыть содержание в полном объеме] **что**. *Рассказать занимательную историю; Рассказать случай в поезде; **Кто толпе мои расскажет думы?*** (Лермонтов)
**2.** [раскрыть тему в общем виде] **о ком-чём** / (разг.) **про кого-что**. *Рассказать о товарищах, о виденном и слышанном; Рассказывать о случае в поезде...*

Из словаря Даля:
[расска́зывать](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), рассказать что, передать в беседе, объявить, поведать, повествовать, подробно сказать словами, устно; иногда говорят и о письменном. ***Путешественники, странники рассказывают много чудес*.**

Мне кажется, что Есенин был настолько очарован женщиной, настолько доверял ей, что готов был поделиться с ней и тоской по родине, и терзаниями (девушка на севере вспоминает ли?), рассказать о бесчисленных красотах и бескрайних полях, — готов был обнажить, распахнуть перед ней свою душу.
Есть мнение, что строки «я расскажу тебе поле» умышленно построены с ошибкой.
Не думаю. Рассказать **о** и **про** — это ведь поделиться только немногим, частным, избранным, кусками, а поэт готов был поверить ей **всё** (поле — всю жизнь!), что в сердце и в памяти.

Позвольте рассказать жизнь мою; времени повесть эта отнимет у вас немного, а знать её ― надобно вам. [Максим Горький. Исповедь (1908)]

Comment: У приведенных вами предложений и предложения у Есенина общий фигуральный прием — и что?! Какое это имеет отношение к пунктуации? Никто не сомневается, что в приведенных вами предложениях не нужно ставить запятую.   Если взять ваш ответ и убрать всё вот это, не имеющее никакого отношения к вопросу, то останется только то, что Есенин умышленно допустил ошибку.(Рекомендую отредактировать ваш ответ, оставив лишь это одно это предложение.) Такой ответ более-менее приемлем, хотя он предполагает два очень сомнительных момента: а) Есенин не понимал, что нельзя выходить за рамки общесогласованных

Comment: правил, потому что у людей будут проблемы с интерпретацией и трудности с восприятием стиха сходу, б) что в русской пунктуации нет возможности обозначить обращение без интонации отступления.

Comment: ,хотя такое обращение(без запятых и интонации отступления) есть при повелении.

Answer (score 2):

> Поэтому, обращаясь в своем стихотворении к Шаганэ, Сергей Есенин **хочет
> рассказать ей о своей родине**. Подчеркивая, что он родом с Севера,
> автор не утруждает себя описанием достопримечательностей Востока,
> считая, что его истинной жемчужиной является робкая и застенчивая
> Шаганэ. **Однако поэт не жалеет красок на то, чтобы рассказать, какова
> его родная сторона, потому что «луна там огромней в сто раз», а
> «волнистая рожь» напоминает цвет его волос. Как рефреном в
> стихотворении «Шаганэ ты моя, Шаганэ…» звучит фраза «я расскажу тебе
> поле», которая умышленно построена с ошибкой, но при этом очень
> созвучна с выражением «я распахну тебе душу».** Таким образом, поэт
> словно бы намекает на то, что его славянская душа так же широка и
> необъятна, как русское поле, и так же щедра, как земля, дающая богатый
> урожай.
>
> [[pishi-stihi.ru](https://pishi-stihi.ru/shagane-ty-moya-shagane-esenin.html)]

Под полем тут понимается природа родного края, где поле является ключевой частью пейзажа. Поэт душевно связан со своим родным краем, с его природой, и он хочет поделиться своим внутренним миром, неотъемлемой частью которого является его родной край, с девушкой.

Эта фраза неоднократно повторяется в стихотворении как припев, и это не случайно. Это ключевая фраза стихотворения.

«Я расскажу тебе поле» — я расскажу тебе о своём родном крае; я хочу раскрыть перед тобой свою душу, поделится, тем что у меня на душе.

Природа родного края является как бы частью поэта:
*«Я готов рассказать тебе поле,
Эти волосы взял я у ржи»*
И он делится частичкой себя с девушкой, приглашает её в свой внутренний мир, в то что родное для него, чего частью он является.

---

Я не думаю, что нужно искать грамматическое оправдание это строчке. Это приём художественной выразительности. С одной стороны «Я расскажу тебе поле» похоже на «Я расскажу тебе историю», что придаёт *полю* смысл *информации*, с другой — «Я расскажу тебе поле» намекает на похожую фразу «Я раскрою тебе душу».

---

«Поле» здесь метонимия родного края: часть заменяет целое.

> **Метони́мия** (др.-греч. μετωνυμία «переименование», от μετά- «через, с помощью» + ὄνομα/ὄνυμα «имя») — вид тропа, словосочетание, в котором одно слово заменяется другим, обозначающим предмет (явление), находящийся в той или иной (пространственной, временной и т. п.) связи с предметом, который обозначается заменяемым словом. Замещающее слово при этом употребляется в переносном значении.
>
> Метонимию следует отличать от метафоры, с которой её нередко путают: метонимия основана на замене слов «по смежности» (**часть вместо целого или наоборот**, представитель класса вместо всего класса или наоборот, вместилище вместо содержимого или наоборот и т. п.), а метафора — «по сходству».
> ...
>
> **Например, фраза «Все флаги в гости будут к нам…» из вступления к поэме «Медный всадник» (1834) А. С. Пушкина, где «флаги» означают «страны» (часть заменяет целое, лат. pars pro toto).**
>
> [[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F)]

Answer (score 1):

Пунктуационные знаки имеют две функции: они обозначают характер произношения и границы при синтаксической сегментации. Обособление слов или сочетаний запятыми обозначает определенную интонацию отступления. Чтобы понять, что это за интонация, обратите внимание на то, как произносится слово «конечно» в следующих предложениях:

— Зачем тебе боксировать с ним, он же профессионал?
— Конечно, мне не победить профессионального боксера, но я просто хочу поучаствовать. («Конечно» произносится с интонацией отступления.)

— Как думаешь, у тебя есть шансы?
— Конечно мне не победить профессионального боксера, идиот, я просто хочу поучаствовать.(Слово «конечно» произносится без интонации отступления.)

— Вы предлагаете при таком диагнозе заниматься спортом?
— Конечно, профессиональным спортсменом ваш сын не станет, но тренировки пойдут ему на пользу. (Слово «конечно» произносится с интонацией отступления.)

— Ты думаешь, что он не станет профессиональным спортсменом?
— Конечно он не станет профессиональным спортсменом: у него средние результаты даже на региональном уровне. («Конечно» произносится без отступления.)

В этих предложениях слово «конечно» обособляется так же, как и обычно обращения. Когда мы обособляем обращение запятыми, то мы обозначаем этими запятыми эту интонацию отступления. Но ничто не мешает нам произнести обращение без такого отступления и исковеркать предложение, как и не обособить запятыми и обозначить такого рода исковерканную интонацию.
И вот такая интонация может подходить для различных песен или стихотворений, где обычно интонация и коверкается.
Обдумав это, я вижу, что, например, пафосные призывы к действию в различных стихах и песнях следует обозначать без этих запятых. Вот несколько строк первого стихотворения такого типа, которое я нашел:
Живи, Украина, прекрасная и сильная
В Советском Союзе ты счастье нашла.
Здесь слово «Украина» произносится без отступления, и эти запятые являются ошибкой.
Я не помнил об этом примечании у Розенталя, но только что нашел подтверждением этому:
Примечания: 1. Не являются обращениями и не выделяются запятыми названия лиц/предметов, находящиеся при форме повелительного наклонения глагола, если она употреблена в значении пожелания (пусть…): Приходи к нему лечиться и корова и волчица (Чук.); Всяк сверчок знай свой шесток (Посл.); ср. также: Кто постарше садитесь.
Все это не относится к этой строчке у Есенина, просто  размышления вслух.

Answer (score 1):

Вопреки своим же принципам я не буду обстоятельно и аргументированно отвечать на основной поставленный вопрос - о пунктуации. Полагаю, тут пунктуация вторична и отчасти факультативна, но при этом и автор не ошибся, выбрав (возможно, чисто интуитивно) такое оформление.

А вот в отношении того, что имелось в виду при использовании особого управления "рассказать поле" - это действительно предмет для обсуждения. Да, наверное, это метафора. "Поле" заменяет слово "повесть" или "рассказ". Во всяком случае иного я нигде не встречал - за исключением не слишком солидных утверждений, что это грамматическая ошибка.  Но метафора эта необычная: она сохраняет не проcто ассоциативную связь, не просто аллюзию на предмет, используемый в качестве метафоры, сам этот заменяющий предмет становится "материализованным", используется без оглядки на его метафорический характер. Можно даже сказать, что это своего рода "реализованная метафора".

С другой стороны, такой особый прием в чем-то близок так называемой "обратной метафоре", смысл такой метафоры раскрывается не сразу, а в последующем тексте. Прием обратной метафоры известен более всего драматургам - со времен древнегреческих авторов и Шекспира до вполне современного *"чеховского ружья"*.
У Есенина же ружье-поле стреляет уже в следующей строчке: "Про волнистую рожь при Луне".
Всё это наводит на мысль, что "поле" здесь совсем не случайно поставлено в ряд однородных членов: *рассказать a) поле б) про рожь при Луне.* В таком контексте никакой другой знак, кроме запятой, не уместен. А в дальнейшем тексте Есенин уже повторно использует зафиксированную метафору без раскрытия её смысла. Кстати говоря, такой прием цикличности свойственен восточной поэзии. И рассматриваемая метафора только усиливает стилизацию под Восток.

Я сознательно писал ответ как небольшое эссе, поэтому ссылками не располагаю.

(+) ======

**@JimKorbett**

> «Поле» в этом стихотворении — это рассказ или повесть?

Мне немного лениво объяснять очевидные вещи человеку, не понимающему даже того, что "картоплю" сажают в огороде, а "поле" как символ России - пшеничное или (как у Есенина) - ржаное.

Но то, что поле здесь "рассказ", известно не только мне.
Вот из интернета первое попавшееся.

> Немаловажно также отметить, что поле в стихотворении Есенина выступает
> как символ. **Оно как бы утратило физические свойства и теперь
> существует как рассказ, как символ искренней тоски по родине.**
> https://literaguru.ru/analiz-stihotvoreniya-shagane-ty-moya-shagane-s-a-esenin/

Тут можно спорить в отношении "утраченных физических свойств" (я-то полагаю, что как раз нет), но понимание "поля" как рассказа, повествования - очевидно.

(++) ====
И еще. Часто в строчке "я расскажу тебе поле" видят не метафору, а метонимию. Иногда просто путают термины, иногда вполне оправдано понимают поле как символ Родины. В таком случае поле - действительно метонимия. Но это о другом. Вопроса о метафоричности замены "повесть"-"поле" (или "повесть"- Родина) это никак не снимает.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129003/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus--------).

Answer (score 0):

***Спасибо всем за ответы!***

Я голосую за все, считая, что в каждом из них  есть полезная информация,  а дополнительные голоса будут выражать мнение участников форума. И постараюсь коротко обозначить свою точку зрения.

1. Да, **это метафора**, и эту тему отвечающие раскрывают очень интересно и познавательно.  Но **необычность метафоры** заключается в сочетании глагола  «рассказать»  с **конкретным, а не отвлеченным** существительным. Можно рассказать ***историю, жизнь,  думы,*** можно рассказывать ***чудеса***, но часто ли  в роли прямого дополнения встречаются  реальные предметы?

Даже понимая метафору и признавая ее  красоту и оригинальность,  каждый раз приходится **настраивать сознание** на правильное восприятие.

2. Но и это еще не все проблемы.  Грамматика предложения такова, что слово «поле»  находится **в позиции обращения**, сравнить: *Я хочу рассказать тебе, **Pole**, про волнистую рожь при луне.* Явно просматривается сочетание «рассказать про волнистую рожь».

Знаки расставлены, и мы видим, что это не обращение, но опять же приходится  делать усилие, чтобы отвлечься **от неверного понимания грамматики**. А в устной речи требуется еще и особое **умение выразительно и понятно прочитать** эти строки.

3. Мне трудно представить, что поэт **тщательно продумывал этот прием**, тем более что он не работал над стихотворением долгое время. Возможно, что в другом тексте метафора была бы очень хороша, если бы она **понималась сразу и легко.**

Я имею в виду следующее. Если, к примеру, переставить местоимение "тебе" в другую позицию, то метафора прочитывается намного яснее: *Я тебе расскажу наше поле, про волнистую рожь при луне.*

4. ***Красивое стихотворение!***  Поэтому и нет особого желания много рассуждать на эту тему,  но хочется просто слушать… **Оно как музыка**, где слов и вовсе нет.

Answer (score 0):

**Поле как символ бесконечного простора родной земли** – к этой теме часто обращался Есенин:

*Гляну в поле, гляну в небо,*

*И в полях и в небе рай.*

*Снова тонет в копнах хлеба*

*Незапаханный мой край.*

Но можно ли представить по одним рассказам, как в жаркий полдень гуляет ветерок по золотым колосьям или «как волнуется рожь при луне»…

**О метафоре…**

***Я готов рассказать тебе поле…***

А поле – это он сам! Он использует себя в качестве **"живой картины"**, поэтому и рассказывает ***поле***, а не ***о поле***.

*Эти волосы взял я у ржи,*

*Если хочешь, на палец вяжи —*

*Я нисколько не чувствую боли.*

**Он сам становится метафорой!** Олицетворением золотой  волны при дыхании ветра и рассказом о родных просторах.

***Посмотри на меня!*** При свете солнца и при свете луны! Посмотри – и ты представишь поле, которое ты никогда не видела.